# Recording to Youtube

Tags: youtube-api

is it possible to record a video straight to Youtube?
Say I have a site, can I have a recording functionality and use some kind of Youtube API that will have the end video posted on Youtube?

Found an upload API but not a streaming upload.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch this vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M74K680WRyc
and read this article: http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2006/12/8387.ars and read this: http://www.youtube.com/my_videos_quick_capture

So basically it is possible with some Flash

Another approach is to save locally, then upload.

Answer (score 0):

Hhhmm, seems like you can't do it.
http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/502962356168707b/f5e6e1b77aefb12d

Answer (score 0):

The web interface described by jao is now at https://www.youtube.com/my_webcam

But it is only a web interface, and you asked for an API that your website could use.

The solution for you is probably the [YouTube Live streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/). You would still probably have to use some Flash-based library to capture a stream from the webcam and send it to the API, though.